# Efficient way to fill a 1D numpy array of variable length with random numbers in different ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, vectorization

I need to fill a length n 1D numpy array with random numbers from the ranges [1,2,...,n], [2,3,...,n], [3,4,...,n], ..., [n-1,n] and [n] respectively. I am looking for a vectorize solution to this problem. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Why does it need to be efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy.random.randint, for this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
res = np.random.randint(np.arange(0, n), n)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[3 3 2 6 6 7 6 8 9 9]
```

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

> Generate a 1 by 3 array with 3 different lower bounds
>
> ```
> np.random.randint([1, 5, 7], 10)
> array([9, 8, 7]) # random
> ```

The more up-to-date alternative is to use [integers](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.integers.html#numpy.random.Generator.integers):

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
rng = np.random.default_rng()
res = rng.integers(np.arange(0, n), n)

print(res)
```

**Note:** The examples above start from `0`, choose the intervals that suit best your problem.